# Find and replace algorithm

Tags: .net, vb.net, replace

i have some text files that contain

`<img width="100"` or
`<img width="1400"` or....

How could i replace all above with the following, since the image width is not static?

```
<img width="200"
```

Comment: Text files or HTML files? If they are simply text files, are they formatted uniformly, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular expression based solution you could use this:

```
string path = "input.html";
string s = File.ReadAllText(path);
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<img width=""\d+""", @"<img width=""200""");
File.WriteAllText(path, s);
```

It will work if your files are from a trusted source in a format that you control. If not and this is HTML, you might want to look at a HTML parser such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

If the files are too large to read into memory you might want to handle the file one line at a time.

It can also sometimes be a good idea to write to a temporary file and only delete the original file once you are sure that the write has succeeded.